# php, mysql - how can you rollback a create or delete table

Tags: php, mysql

Well.. title kind of says it all.

Let's say I have a script that creates some tables, then insert some data in them.
Sometimes an error occurs.

Is there anyway to rollback the create tables? Or I have to delete them manually?

Comment: RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html

Comment: @FerdiDuisters What do you mean?

Comment: @Jocelyn See answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html).

> The CREATE TABLE statement in InnoDB is processed as a single transaction. This means that a ROLLBACK from the user does not undo CREATE TABLE statements the user made during that transaction.

Comment: I've tried it and can confirm this ;) +1

Comment: Could not accept earlier... 10 min rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting data through the php script, you can issue the relevant `DROP TABLE` query when you detect that the insertion of a row has failed

Answer (score 0):

Of Course you can't rollback as the create statement is DDl

Answer (score -2):

MYSQL: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Try mysqli, you have a rollback function.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php

Comment: You CAN NOT roll back a 'CREATE TABLE' statement using MySQL. It does not matter if you are using PHP or not, it does not matter if you are using mysql_* functions or mysqli_* functions.